# Python Pip Packages downloaded are not being loaded to VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to use python packages i installed from pip, onto vscode. There are 4 pips, that are not showing up, but I'm mostly concerned about discord package for now.

I've tried various solutions over the past two days, which ive screen captured - updating versions, making sure installation to PATH, selecting the python interpretor on VSCode, etc.

[packages1 cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d6dp.png) [discord package cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7czoB.png)

My VScode has a remote account to Harvard CS50 online course and has all their libraries/modules working. [VSCode Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFsvj.png)

Here are screenshots to confirm updated versions of python and pip: [version1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW1U8.png)

Here are the environmental variables screenshots from the settings [environmentVar1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L4z8.png) [environmentVar2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awl61.png)

Here is my screenshot of the python interpretor in VScode. Ive selected other ones to see if discord imports, and nothing happens. [pythonInterp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT6t4.png)

Comment: Your "screenshot to confirm updated version" shows Python 3.10.4.  That's not the one in your `pythonInterp` screenshot.

Comment: @TimRoberts I see. How do I fix this? 

Does this have anything to do with the remote VSCode account (CS50 Github) interfering with the python installed on my computer's access to VSCode?

Comment: If you're running Python remotely, then you need to install the package on the remote system.  That's the key -- you need to make sure you have installed the package in the Python installation you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Roberts found the problem in the comments:

My VSCode was connected to a remote account, so the packages I downloaded to the computer did not load onto VSCode.

I had to either download those packages on the remote account OR remove the remote account and select the correct Python in the python selector on VSCode. I did the latter, and saw the discord import working perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).